# How to deal with a dataframe containing columns with mixed types?

Tags: python, pandas, types, dtype

I have a pandas `dataframe` (in memory) with columns containing mixed types, how do I handle it?

Comment: what do you mean by "handle it"? what do you actually want to do?

Comment: Dataframes with mixed types create issues (save a file to feather, run a linear regression with statsmodels, etc). I feel that it is desirable to have a dataframe without mixed types. I asked a quite general question because I did not want to be specific to any issue it creates, or in the case that someone answers by arguing for keeping mixed types in the dataframe.

Comment: But do you mean different types across columns? different types within the rows of a column? Nothing about this question strikes me as clear or actionable.

Comment: In other words, a question worded like "how do I make sure all of my dataframe columns are numeric?" is an actual problem that can be solved

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Copy-paste the two functions below, execute them,  then run `df_cleaned = df.pipe(clean_mixed_dtypes)`

---

First, you have to list the columns in which your `dataframe` has mixed types.

```py
def get_mixed_columns(df_):
    return (df_
                .select_dtypes("object") # performance gain: only columns whith an object dtype can have mixed types
                .apply(pd.api.types.infer_dtype) # get a string describing the type
                .loc[lambda x: x.str.contains("mixed")] # select columns with mixed dtypes
           )
df.pipe(get_mixed_columns) # to observe columns that have mixed dtype
```

Second, you have to set a unique type for all the objects in these columns. You can transform them to string (maybe you should avoid it if the objects inside are exotic objects (e.g. an image, a dataframe, a blob, etc)).

However, if your types are `mixed-integer-float` you can assign them to `float` dtype.

```py
def clean_mixed_dtypes(df_):
    s_mixed_cols = df_.pipe(get_mixed_columns)
    return df_.astype({
    **{col:'str' for col in s_mixed_cols.loc[lambda x: x != "mixed-integer-float"].index},
    **{col:'float' for col in s_mixed_cols.loc[lambda x: x == "mixed-integer-float"].index},
    })
df_without_mixed_dtypes = df.pipe(clean_mixed_dtypes)
```

ps: before doing that, you may want to check that the mixed types are not due to data artefacts:

```py
(df[get_mixed_columns(df).index]
.applymap(lambda x: str(type(x)))
.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(normalize=True))) #There is probably a better way to do this
```